what can be the code of this series which takes 3 values
I am typing my masters thesis in LaTeX and I am unable to write the code of this  product which breaks into three different values
So, Sum $S$ breaks into

I know the code of $n$ Choose  $k$ and $\alpha$ but I don't know how to type the code of a function that breaks into 3 parts.
Can you please help me with this?
Thank you.

Use the cases environment.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
        \binom{n}{k}\binom{D(\alpha-k)+n}{n} & \text{if } \alpha-k\geq0 \\
        0 & \text{if } \frac{-n}{D}\leq\alpha-k<0 \\
        (-1)^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{D(k-\alpha)-1}{n} & \text{if }\alpha-k\leq\frac{-n}{D}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

if you want display style math, write \displaystyle at the start of each line inside the cases environment (write \displaystyle\binom{n}{k}..., etc).

\dbinom, rather than \displaystyle\binom
